# Change the display name of a calculation in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

How can the display name of a computed field be customized?  Note the entire calculation is being displayed as the field label in the tooltip :

[image]

When attempting to customize that calculated field there is no apparent way to change the display name:

[image]

**Update** Here is the set of `dimensions` and `measures`: notice the last `dimension` on the `rows` is the calculated field. *That* is what I am unable to discover how to name/alias/..

[image]

Comment: I've never noticed that. Are you saying that it only is doing that in the tooltip and in what scenario is it doing it? Normally the display name of a calculated field is exactly what you name it.

Comment: "name it" : where can it be named?  I have updated the question with the dims and measures including the specific calculated field

Comment: Oh, okay I think you need to create it as a calculated field. It could be that it is a calculation in the "Shelf" in the way you have displayed it. You would need to go to your list of fields displayed on the left, right click and click "Create", and then copy your formula into that, and be sure to name it what you want and then save it. Then it will show up as a field in the list of fields on the left.

Comment: You could also drag that pill into your measures section, it'll create the calc field pill there, then you could right click to rename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create it as a calculated field. It could be that it is a calculation in the "Shelf" in the way you have displayed it. You would need to go to your list of fields displayed on the left, right click and click "Create", and then copy your formula into that, and be sure to name it what you want and then save it. Then it will show up as a field in the list of fields on the left.

Answer (score 5):

Right click the calculation and select **Edit in Shelf**. Move your cursor to the first character and press `Shift`+`Enter` to add a new line above your calculation. On this blank line, add the alias in the form of a comment, e.g. `//AverageScore`.

Note that making changes to the field can sometimes undo this and it will need to be reapplied.